# How to do a Nunit test with parameters?

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to do a `[Test]` which receives a parameter, and not using `[TestCase]` as this parameter can take multiple values. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
    [Test]
    static public void NUnitWriter(int errorCode)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual (0, errorCode);
    }
```

This function just receives an error code and if it's not 0 (a problem occurred), assert.

Comment: That test makes no sense - you're asserting that your test was given the right argument? Where's the system under test?

Comment: yes the parameter is valid, there is no way it is not, it is validated before. All I want is to produce a xml file with Nunit with all error codes different from 0 (for jenkins)

Comment: You want the test method to produce a xml file? Can you update the question. Or do you mean take in parameters from a xml file?

Comment: your answer helped me do it. I can update about the xml file if you wan but I don't think it will add to the discussion since it's solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass in variables use [Data driven tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx)

```
[DataSource(@"Provider=Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0; Data Source=C:\Data\MathsData.sdf;", "Numbers")]
[Test]
static public void NUnitWriter()
{
    int x = 0
    int errorCode = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["ErrorCode"]);
    Assert.AreEqual (x, errorCode);
}
```

Passing in from [Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    [DataSource("Table:CSharpDataDrivenTests.xml#FirstTable")]
    [Test]
    static public void NUnitWriter()
    {
        int x = 0
        int errorCode = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["ErrorCode"]);
        Assert.AreEqual (x, errorCode);
    }
```