# How to programmatically tell NUnit to repeat a test?

Tags: c#, nunit

**How to programmatically tell NUnit to repeat a test?**

***Background:***
I'm running NUnit from within my C# code, using a SimpleNameFilter and a RemoteTestRunner. My application reads a csv file, TestList.csv, that specifies what tests to run. Up to that point everything works ok.

***Problem:***
The problem is when I put the same test name two times in my TestList file. In that case, my application correctly reads and loads the SimpleNameFilter with two instances of the test name. This filter is then passed to the RemoteTestRunner. Then, Nunit executes the test only once. It seems that when Nunit sees the second instance of a test it already ran, it ignores it.

How can I override such behavior? I'd like to have NUnit run the same test name two times or more as specified in my TestList.csv file.

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: Have a look at [data driven tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622972/how-to-do-a-nunit-test-with-parameters/30623089#30623089)

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to do this?

Comment: Hi Lloyd: That looks really good, but, it seems it only applies to the Microsoft Unit Testing tool and not NUnit?

Comment: Hi Jeroen: The reason is that in TestList file I'd like to call the same test, but, with different parameters. For example, I have a test that checks a temperature sensor, but, I may have a variable number of temperature sensors: readTemperature sensor0, min0, max0; readTemperature sensor1, min1, max1; readTemperature sensorN, minN, maxN;

Comment: The [`[TestCaseSource]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.4) attribute should allow you to programmatically  determine how many times you want to perform a test, and with wath parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running an identical test twice should have the same result.  An individual test can either pass or it can fail.  If you have tests that work sometimes and fail another then it feels like the wrong thing is happening.  Which is why NUnit doesn't support this out of the box.  I imagine it would also cause problems in the reporting of the results of the test run, does it say that test X worked, or failed if both happened?

The closest thing you're going to get in Nunit is something like the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute (which you already seem to know about).  You can use TestCaseSource to specify a method, which can in turn, read from a file.  So, you could for example have a file "cases.txt" which looks like this:

```
Test1,1,2,3
Test2,wibble,wobble,wet
Test1,2,3,4
```

And then use this from your tests like so:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("Test1Source")]
public void Test1(string a, string b, string c) {
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("Test2Source")]
public void Test2(string a, string b, string c) {
}

public IEnumerable Test1Source() {
    return GetCases("Test1");
}

public IEnumerable Test2Source() {
    return GetCases("Test2");
}

public IEnumerable GetCases(string testName) {
    var cases = new List<IEnumerable>();

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"cases.txt").Where(x => x.StartsWith(testName));
    foreach (var line in lines) {
        var args = line.Split(',');
        var currentcase = new List<object>();
        for (var i = 1; i < args.Count(); i++) {
            currentcase.Add(args[i]);
        }
        cases.Add(currentcase.ToArray());
    }
    return cases;
}
```

This is obviously a very basic example, that results in `Test1` being called twice and `Test2` being called once, with the arguments from the text file.  However, this is again only going to work if the arguments passed to the test are different, since nunit uses the arguments to create a unique test name, although you could work around this by having the test source generate a unique number for each method call and passing it to the test as an extra argument that the test simply ignores.

An alternative would be for you to run the nunit from a script that calls nunit over and over again for each line of the file, although I imagine this may cause you other issues when you're consolidating the reporting from the multiple runs.

Comment: Thank you forsvarir. This is a great answer. You gave some very good pointers to consider. I'll follow through with the TestCaseSource.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5

> TestCaseAttribute serves the dual purpose of marking a method with
>   parameters as a test method and providing inline data to be used when
>   invoking that method. Here is an example of a test being run three
>   times, with three different sets of data:

```
[TestCase(12,3, Result=4)]
[TestCase(12,2, Result=6)]
[TestCase(12,4, Result=3)]
public int DivideTest(int n, int d)
{
  return( n / d );
}
```

Comment: Hi Vitaly: This is good, but, the number of times the test gets fixed at compile time. Also, in your answer the test data is fixed as well, that could be fixed with a TestCaseSource(). However, in my application, I don't know beforehand how many times the test will be called. What I'm looking for is to tell NUnit to run a test as many times as that test name is included in my TestList.csv file.